# Specified cast is not valid LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
 public static DataTable GetData(string listname)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn IdProject = dt.Columns.Add("IdProject", typeof(int));
            DataColumn Count = dt.Columns.Add("Count", typeof(int));

            table = Income(listname);
            var query = (from b in table.AsEnumerable()
                         group b by b.Field<int>("IdProject") into g
                         select new
                         {
                             IdProject = g.Key,
                             Count = g.Count()
                         }).ToList();

            foreach (var x in query)
            { dt.Rows.Add(x.IdProject, x.Count); }

            return dt;

        }
```

При отладке на строке с `b.Field<int>("IdProject") into g` получается исключение "Specified cast is not valid". Но я не понимаю, что не так с приведением типов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, в таблице `table` колонка `IdProject` имеет какой-то другой тип.

Comment: Довольно странно, но да. IdProject формируется из шейрпоинта и по скольку я выставлял там количество знаков после комы не "Авто", а "0", то оно хранилось как double. Внезапное открытие, спасибо.